# svn not able to check out from svn repository OPTIONS issue

Tags: svn, vpn, smartsvn, svn-checkout

I am trying to check out a repository using Smart svn on a mac. I have pinged the server successfully.

i also tried using the command line svn checkout and got the same issue, so I believe that there's something not configured correctly.

Here is the error I am seeing

`OPTIONS of 'MY_SERVER + svn path': could not connect to server (MY_SERVER)`

I have omitted the names of my server as this is for a private project.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like i was having VPN issues at the time but was unaware of them, i have straightened this out. Thank you to all who viewed this.